Can there be a progressive and slow vacuum transition event instead of a sudden one?
I have a question on transition events between vacua, and what do our models predict that would happen:
Could there be a transition between vacua without involving a sudden event like a bubble nucleation? But rather instead a proggressive and slow process? Is this an example of that: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2401.08801?

What makes you/these authors believe that there is a true vacuum in the first place?

@FlatterMann my question also applies for two given vacua with similar vacuum energies, not necessarily a metastable and a true one

So have you or these authors seen a second vacuum? How did they cause the tunneling event in the lab?

@FlatterMann My questions are of course based on a theoretical model. It would be as if I opened a question about cosmological inflation, hawking radiation, string theory... Not everything in physics has to be experimentally verified to be discussed

Well, technically physics is science and science is the rational description of nature. It's not the mathematical discussion of arbitrary models that don't describe nature. Having said that, you/these authors are saying that such a vacuum has an energy. Energy is the ability of a system to perform work on another system. So what other system can a vacuum perform work on? What if the total energy of the universe is zero? What does it mean that a universe of zero energy is performing work on another universe of zero energy? These are obvious physical questions, even for purely fictional models.

True vacuum by definition is completely empty, so it's vacuum energy is $\large 0$ and as such,- such transitions (between false and true vacuum) is impossible, because they are completely different entities (omitting true vacuum Physicality question).

@AgniusVasiliauskas but, false vacua don't have 0 vacuum energy, and I am asking about a false vacuum tunneling into a true one, a classic vacuum decay scenario. The only particularity here is that according to the Coleman paper this decay would not be possible if the false vacuum had a vacuum energy that would be close to the true one. But I've found other papers linked in OP where it's shown to be possible. The thing is that they do not include gravity apparently, while Coleman does. So my question is: Can we have a vacuum decay if the metastable vacuum has a similar energy to the true one?

It is notable that the authors of that paper still claimed the speed was ~1, so even the slow decay is near lightspeed. Still, I don't quite see how they derive it. It is a good question.

@AndersSandberg I contacted the authors of the other paper and they clarified that it would still involve a bubble nucleation event. I changed the question now asking if there could be a slow and progressive vacuum transition event without bubble nucleation. Do you think that this paper an example of such mechanism: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2401.08801?

What you are essentially looking for is an adiabatic field evolution from one vacuum to another vacuum.
If the potential is constant in time, this is hard to imagine. The field will naturally sit in one vacuum throughout some region of space. To move the field in that region to another vacuum adiabatically, you would need some mechanism to pump energy in the field everywhere in this region to "push" it over the activation energy it would need to cross the potential barrier and "fall" into the true vacuum. (Although -- this is just offhand speculation -- maybe you could do something like this if you had another field that was evolving in time and pumped energy into the "false vacuum" field). Quantum tunneling gets around this by simply tunneling through the potential barrier, but the tunneling rate is going to be suppressed by the volume of space involved in tunneling, so you are going to tend to form a bubble.
However, if the potential is not constant, then you can imagine such a scenario quite naturally. Thermal effects can lead to an effective time dependent potential. For example, it's believed that the effective thermal potential for the Higgs in the early Universe would have a minimum at zero vev. Essentially thermal corrections add a term like $-\frac{1}{2} m_{\rm eff}^2(T) \phi^2$ to the scalar potential, where $m_{\rm eff}(T)$ is a temperature dependent correction. This gets added to the quadratic term of the Higgs potential, $+\frac{1}{2}m^2 \phi^2$. If $m_{\rm eff}(T) > m$, then the effective potential will have a minimum instead of a maximum at $\phi=0$. So in the early, hot Universe, the field will tend to sit at $\phi=0$. Then as $T$ changes (decreases as the Universe cools due to expansion), if $m_{\rm eff}(T)$ varies continuously, then the minimum of the effective potential will continuously move from $\phi=0$ to $\phi=\phi_0$ (where $\phi_0$ is the Higgs vev today), and the field will adiabatically follow the minimum.

so these kind of transitions would be possible thanks to thermal fluctuations? Also, another related question: As fas as I know a vacuum bubble could arise by quantum fluctuations in a region with a high energy density. Even if the new vacuum bubble collapsed could it make the "parent" vacuum transition to a higher vacuum energy level? @Andrew

@vengaq Yeah, exactly, What I described is more of an effective field theory way to say it, but a more microphysical version is that at high temperatures the field is buffeted around by large thermal fluctuations so its vev averages to zero, and as the thermal fluctuations decrease, the field settles into a ground state (minimum of the "true" instead of "effective" potential). There are scenarios where the new vacuum bubble collapses, but I haven't heard of the version where this changes the "parent" vacuum (although maybe it could happen!)

As an aside, I believe one way you can slow down the bubble wall expansion is if there is fluid present in the false vacuum, and then turbulence and drag can affect the evolution of the bubble wall.

thanks for the info! Finally, I got two more questions, regarding this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.4487) I was wondering if you could help me with them (instead of opening another question, since I've been doing a few lately). 1. If two vacuum bubble events collide, the resultant energy could trigger an up-tunneling of the vacuum, and this could happen between two bubbles of terminal vacua, as it's indicated in the article. However, the new vacuum could not have a higher energy level than the parent vacuum. But could it possibly reach the same energy level as the parent vacuum? @Andrew


Is it completely impossible that the new vacuum could have a higher vacuum energy than the parent one?

I mean, for example, consider that the original vacuum "A" had some energy content (thermal, potential, kinetic...) in addition to its given vacuum energy level. After the collision of vacuum bubbles "B", we get the vacuum "C", which has a lower vacuum energy level than "A". But couldn't the energy content of vacuum "C", which should have been conserved all this time, be susceptible of causing a tunneling to a vacuum with a higher energy level? @Andrew
